# Regular Expression validation doesn't allow home, end, arrow keys to work

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Problem: I have an html text input that uses the following code in the `onpress`, `onkeydown`, and `onkeyup` events:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/, '')
```

This works for alphanumeric validation, but it doesn't allow the cursor to be placed using the home key, the end key, or the arrow keys; the cursor can only be moved using the backspace key. To be honest, this is desirable behavior in some cases, but not in others.

Why this behavior in Firefox and Chrome (haven't tested yet in IE)? My quess is it has to do with the `this.value =` part putting the cursor at the end, because I've never seen regular expressions for arrow keys and such.

Comment: It's not the regex, you're probably returning false somewhere, and cancelling that key. Please post some more code.

Comment: That should have been all the necessary code, but I posted the entire input tag's code (very redundant). While backspace works, delete does not, and neither does home or the arrow keys. I think, as stated in the question, that this has to do with the this.value part.

Comment: You're right. Since you're replacing the whole contents on every keystroke (actually, 3 times per keystroke), the caret is being placed at the end after the replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're replacing the whole contents on every keystroke (actually, 3 times per keystroke), the caret is being placed at the end after the replace.

I suggest another approach: only replace the field's contents if validation doesn't pass:

```html
<input id="uname" type="text">
```

```js
var f = document.getElementById('uname');
f.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    var regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/;
    if(regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(regex, '')  
    }
});
```

<sub>The JavaScript snippet above should be added inside a `<script>` tag just before `</body>` (or be wrapped in a document.ready/DOMContentLoaded/window.onload handler to make sure the field already exists when it runs).</sub>

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zjSR5/1/)

Comment: +1 for the unobtrusiveness as above, it's definitely more unobtrusive, but without the script tags will the OP (or others) know how to apply it? (I'm being picky, I know).

Comment: @iain Okay, added a note about that.

Comment: I would recommend adding a `g` modifier in the regex (`/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g`), otherwise the user can copy and paste an invalid string that won't be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:  First, you're firing the event three times, that seems unnecessary.  Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function forceAlphaNumeric(field){
        var invalidChars = /[^a-z0-9]/ig
        if(field.value.match(invalidChars))
            field.value = field.value.replace(invalidChars, '');
     }
</script>
<input id="uname" type="text" onkeypress="forceAlphaNumeric(this);" />
```

Comment: +1 for the unobtrusiveness. I'd want to add +2 if you had grabbed the element _within_ the script to make it truly unobtrusive :)

Comment: @iain No!  This way, he can force multiple fields to be alphaNumeric with a single piece of code.  This is clearly the better solution, because as he adds ways to enforce the alphaNumeric nature of a field, he can change it in one place and affect everytime this is called on a page (at least), but with a proper library structure - across a whole site!

Comment: @FrankeTheKneeMan yes, but he could just add them in the script by binding the function to the event there after calling `document.getElementById`. That'd be my preference anyway. The function could be in a separate script that is included where needed, and even have a helper function to take a list of id's and do the binding. YMMV.